# Why doesn't git ask for username and password every time I try to push from vs code's integrated terminal?

Tags: git, github

Whenever I git push anything on vs code's integrated terminal, it doesn't ask for username and password. But whenever I try to push from the main terminal of ubuntu, it asks for username and password, of which's support was stopped by github. What am I missing here ?

I just git add remote the url in vscode nothing else.

Comment: I don't know what VSCode is doing, but ultimately, it sounds like you should switch from HTTPS to SSH.

Comment: @wjandrea I switched to SSH but the cli is saying permission denied, whereas it's still working on vs code's integrated terminal.

Comment: Did you do the whole SSH setup? generate a key, install it on GitHub, etc?

Comment: @wjandrea No. Do you have any link to that ?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh